# ArcGIS: Reclassify Values as Parameter in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, reclassify

Is there a way in ArGIS' Model Builder to set the values for reclassification (Tool Reclassify) as Model Parameters? The Reclassification is an important part of my model and I need to be able to change the threshold values for reclassification in an easy way in the model window.

The only workaround I can so far think of, would be to create several rasters by using the Raster Calculator, using Double variables which can be set as Parameters...

Comment: [From the help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-tool-with-modelbuilder-tutorial.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_EA194F1783B64C6D880A0338EEF0F569) (Make variable from reclassification parameter and then model parameter to expose in dialog)

Comment: Thank you for the link. However I am afraid this will not work when used as simply one tool in a complex model chain; with the task to reclassify intermediate rasters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Calculate Value](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-value.htm) with an output parameter type of `Remap` to accomplish dynamic reclassification of intermediate results.

Here, I'm use `Iterate Field Values` to loop over a table with different reclass values. `%Max%` is a model variable and `%Value%` is the current table value. If you export the Reclassify GP tool to Python, you'll find that the remap parameter (for ranges at least) can be accomplished via [RemapRange](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-spatial-analyst/an-overview-of-transformation-classes.htm). I just did it with `str.format()` since it's a simple remap. For more complicated ones, you'll probably want to use something like

```
str(arcpy.sa.RemapRange([[0, 75, 75], [76, 150, 150]]))
```

[image]

This submodel is part of a much larger series of models that takes an input raster and reclassifies it multiple times based on the number of rows in a record set. The end user never specifies a remap or reclassification parameter.